# Page won't show japanese characters from XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have some jQuery code to show elements from a variable in which is stored the xml content. It fires on document load.
I don't know why when I use japanese only some question marks are shown instead of the word. This is true for other languages which do not use latin alphabet, too. The files are saved using UTF-8 encoding.
If I write something in japanese on the HTML page the characters are correctly shown.

jQuery file "xml-script.js":

```
jp_JP = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> <language> <menuwords> <classic>クラシック</classic> </menuwords> </language>
var xml = jp_JP;

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml); 
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);

var $menuwords = $xml.find("menuwords");

$menuwords.each(function(){
    classic = $(this).find('classic').text();
});

$('h1').html(classic);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1></h1>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/xml-script.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
I also noticed that the xml variable content is modified after I open the page in fact the japanese characters become "?" even in the file. I guess it might be a parsing problem.

Comment: Are you saving the page from your editor in UTF-8 format?

Comment: Yes. I'll add it to the post.

Comment: does js file contains UTF-8 BOM?